# App crashing when upgraded xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, ios-simulator

I have this problem of my app crashing (only when press a certain UIButton) after i upgraded my xcode to the latest 3.2.5 and iPhone simulator 4.2. It works fine in my friend laptop, who hasn't upgraded yet. 
I googled for answers, but most of them faces problem only crashing in simulator but not device. Mine crashes for both.

Anyone has any idea about this issue? 
I cant seem to find any solution.

UPDATE: Got this error only when run application on device.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
(gdb)

Comment: What error is being thrown if any?  Anything in console?  Anything in debugger?

Comment: If its not showing on the console then did u try with NSZombie?

Comment: Run with debugger attached, and watch the console.

Comment: Down voted, insufficient data supplied to be able to answer the question. Please supply the errors, logs etc showing what has happened. Otherwise people are just guessing trying to figure this out.

Comment: hi guys! thanks for all the comments! 
@Stefan: There's nothing shown in the debugger. Not even the most common NSException or whatever. Thats why i cant seem to find what is happening exactly.
@Aditya: I tried using the Zombie in the instrument, but its working perfectly fine there! Weird huh. But in Leaks, it will break tho. :/
@Eiko: There's nothing shown in the console, except for some NSLog, I've previously input.
@Derek: Sorry for the overlook of insufficient data, kind of new here. :)

Comment: Okay, got an update. I tried running this on the device, i got an error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: @funatsg: try doing a build and analyze, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this! Due to some duplicate codings. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from your device, run a "Clean" in Xcode, and then try again. Sometimes things just get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your project settings; more specifically, those that set directories.  Also, make sure the appropriate files are in their respective build phases.

Comment: yeah checked! but still doesn't works. How do i know whether the files are in the correct build phases? What do you meant by that? Sorry, kind of new of iphone programming. :(